# cookie expires and addhours() go wrong

Tags: asp.net, iis, cookies

I have build several websites that work with the same principle:
If your login is successfull a cookie is created.
If not, you will always be redirected back to the login page.
Even if you write the full url for the default.aspx page, if the cookie is not present it redirects to the login page.

Now in my websites I always set the value of the cookie expiration time to a few hours after creation.

so:

`mycookie.expires = now.addHours(4)`

Today I found out the website is not getting passed the login page in Chrome and FireFox. In IE it works as expected.
Inspection of the cookie in FireFox shows the expiration time is about a month earlier. This is strange and obvious this is why the website is not getting passed by the login page. The cookie is expired the moment it gets created.

After changing the code to:

`mycookie.expires = now.addDays(1)`

everything works normally.

Is this some kind of bug in .NET 4.5, IIS8 or in the browsers?
Has anyone experienced this as well?

I find it strange it happens both in Chrome and FF. Are they secretly using the same browser engine???

Comment: How are you sure that this change fixed the problem? Was that the _only_ thing you did, and if so, can you explain how to reproduce the problem? Can you show code that actually compiles? Or might it just have something to do with the Daylight Savings change of past weekend?

Comment: The code is quite simple, just create a httpcookie object and add it to the request. I found this after three hours of searching, trying to locate the issue. I noticed the wrong date of the expiration of the cookie by accident. I have tried addYears(10) first, that worked, then I tried with addDays(1), that worked as well, Then with addDays(0.5) which didn't work. I understood from users the problem was there before the weekend, so no, the time change wasn't the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. Also, does this happen on every machine, or just this particular server? If so, is it in a different timezone? What is `now` and how do you obtain it?